# Select the value of tr->td data from a model id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am no expert in jquery so seeking help i have bootstrap model which is having **unique Id** in which we can get data in tabular format Each row will have comment and timestamp  i need to pick the value of td data with highest timestamp (latest):

For Example i need to pick value of `second tr column value which is "testing"` as its timestamp is greater than first tr .  Note these tr will keep increasing based on the data these are dynamic

```
div class="modal fade" id="QCPopUpMessageModal" role="dialog" style="display: none;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- modal-sm,modal,lg -->
      <div class="modal-content panel-warning">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">×</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modalBodypop autoflow-scroll">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
               <thead>
                  <tr class="info">
                     <td>COMMENT</td>
                     <td>USERNAME</td>
                     <td>LASTUPDATEDTIMESTAMP</td>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="warning">
                     <td>01262023</td>
                     <td>ek4126</td>
                     <td>1/26/2023, 11:27:24 AM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="warning">
                     <td>testing</td>
                     <td>C7K4KV</td>
                     <td>2/6/2023, 1:52:54 PM</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="info">
                     <td colspan="1">Enter New Comment</td>
                     <td><input type="text" id="saveCommentInput" style="width: 100%;"></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveQCcomment(this)">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all `<tr>` as `tr`

Create `dates` array from `tr`

Get latest date as `max`

Use `filter` to get latest data from `tr`

```js
const tr = $("#QCPopUpMessageModal tr.warning");
const dates = tr
  .map(function () {
    return new Date($("td", this).eq(2).text());
  })
  .get();
const max = Math.max.apply(null, dates);
const res = tr
  .filter(function () {
    return new Date($("td", this).eq(2).text()).valueOf() == max;
  })
  .map(function () {
    return $("td", this).eq(0).text();
  })[0];

console.log(res);
```

If new row will be append at the end:

```js
console.log($("tr.warning").last().find("td").eq(0).text());
```